# OMG! We're Twinning!

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes

## Introduction

We define **twin primes** as two natural numbers `p,p+2` which both are prime.

***Example***: `5` and `7` are twin primes.

Let's define the *twin number* of some set of numbers as the number of twin prime numbers in that set

***Example***: {`6`,`7`,`11`,`13`,`18`,`29`,`31`} has a twin number `4`, since there are four twin primes; `11,13` and `29,31`.

## Program

**Input**: A number `n`

**Output**: The twin number of the set of all **natural** numbers below `n`

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytes wins.

Comment: Do you have some test cases?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Natural number must also be whole numbers, and I assume he only wants us to deal with whole number primes

Comment: @SpeedyNinja Sorry, I misremembered the definition of natural numbers, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the definition. The example set seems to have 4 twin primes. Are we supposed to count the number of pairs? If so, does **3**, **5**, **7** count as *two* pairs? What if one of the primes is in the set, but the other one isn't?

Comment: @Dennis 'twas but a mistake. fixed.

Comment: Not much clearer I'm afraid. *twin number `2`, since there are four twin primes*

Comment: @Dennis what a blunder

Comment: OK, I'm reopening, but a few test cases would still be helpful.

Comment: I think the wording is a little off. Are you defining twin to be *one* prime? Typically we would refer to the *pair* as a twin. Just add test cases and then your wording is less critical.

Comment: What happens if only one of the pair is in the set, e.g. `{11}`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Find the Nth pair of twin primes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31822/20260). This one has you count them and that one has you generate them counting up, but the core process of enumerating and checking twin primes is the same.

Comment: @sp3000 In that case, since 11 belongs to a pair, it's twin number is 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 7 bytes

```
qZqd2=s
```

This solution exploits the fact that the [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) (the difference between successsive prime numbers) is always >= 2 (with the exception being the gap between 2 and 3). Because of this fact, all *twin primes* will be successive prime numbers. In this solution we just compute the differences between all primes less than the input `n` and count how many of these differences are equal to 2.

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cVpxZDI9cw&input=MzI)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input, N
q   % Subtract one from the input (N-1)
Zq  % Get an array of all primes <= (N-1)
d   % Compute successive differences (prime gaps)
2=  % Create a boolean array indicating which prime gaps are equal to 2
s   % Count the TRUE values in this array to determine the twin number
    % Implicitly display the result
```

If you instead want the *not* the number of pairs but the number of primes that are *part of a pair*, the following would work

```
qZqt!-|H=az
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cVpxdCEtfEg9YXo&input=MzI)

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 10 bytes

```
ZlZd~Bx©{2
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=WmxaZH5CeMKpezI)

### Explanation

```
ZlZd~Bx©{2
    ~B     all numbers satisfying
       ©{  the prime condition ("the prime directive"?)
      x    below x
  Zd       (the differences between indices)
Zl       2 count the number of 2's
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 43 + 8 (`-rprime` flag) = 51 bytes

```
->n{Prime.each(n-1).count{|i|(i-2).prime?}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>54</s>  53 bytes

```perl6
{2*(3..$_).rotor(3=>-1).grep: {all .[0,2]».is-prime}}
{2*(3,5...$_).rotor(2=>-1).grep: {all $_».is-prime}}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  2
  *
  (3,5...$_)        # odd numbers
  .rotor( 2 => -1 ) # grab 2 then backup one, repeat
  .grep:            # find all that match the following
    {
      # create a Junction object of the following
      all

        # call .is-prime on both elements of the
        # list given to this inner block
        $_».is-prime
    }
}
```